# Azure Pipeline - cannot login to azure account, but it works from the build machine itself

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm encountering an issue with an Azure Pipeline (PowerShell script) where I'm unable to log in to my Azure account. Specifically, I'm receiving error message: `2023-03Method 'get_SerializationSettings' in type 'Microsoft.Azure.Management.Internal.Resources.ResourceManagementClient' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Common, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation.`

However, I've found that the task runs without any issues when I manually execute it using PowerShell command line on the same build machine where the task is being executed.

Here is my script:

`$applicationId = "015e10e9-0136-4393-xxxx-"; $securePassword = "QGf8Q~x-xxxxxx" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force $credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $applicationId, $securePassword Connect-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $credential -TenantId "b49ce02b-187d-xxx"`

Comment: Windows could be blocking authentication using username and password.  Most windows systems require authentication using encrypted credentials and sending password unencrypted is not secure.  Connect to the SQL Server using SQL Server Management Server.  The login window show either SQL Credentials or Windows Credentials.  Then in explorer under Management will be the log files which will show the account and reason for connection failure.  If there is no log than windows blocked the connection.

Comment: Are you able to verify your service connection from azure devops to azure portal?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you to use(try) with latest Powershell Az Modules, instead of AzureRM modules.

```
$ApplicationId = "0000-0000-0000-0000"
$Password = "000000000000000"
$TenantId = "0000-0000-000-000"
$subscriptionId = "0000-0000-0000-0000"
$SecuredPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $ApplicationId, $SecuredPassword
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $TenantId -Credential $Credential
$sub = Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId
Set-AzContext -Subscription $sub
``
```